# swift Publish plug in issue

Tags: swift, plugins, publish, blogs

I was trying to make my website with Publish for swift made by Sundell.
It secesfully built and I made my new theme.
Now I want to add Splash plug in for code Highlight and utterance for comments.

on the Sundell's github I found https://github.com/johnsundell/splashpublishplugin How to install Splash. and I followed it but It didn't work. In my console show me Splash is install, but my code block is still not changed.

I add this code block main.swift file.

```swift
import SplashPublishPlugin
...
try DeliciousRecipes().publish(using: [
    .installPlugin(.splash(withClassPrefix: "classPrefix"))
    ...
])
```

the problem is I already have

```swift
try MyWebsite().publish(withTheme: .myTheme)
```

this line in the bottom. I tried to combine it but they give me error.

what do I more to make my code block pretty?

only I can see How to add disqus comment, but I want to use utterance. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this question is quite old, but still the answer can help anyone finding this.

To add a plugin while still using a theme, you can update your code in `main.swift` file like this:

```swift
try MyWebsite().publish(
  withTheme: .myTheme,
  plugins: [
    .splash(withClassPrefix: "")
  ]
)
```

The list of plugins provided (here only one) will be installed "at the start of the publishing process".

Then follow [instructions found in the documentation](https://github.com/JohnSundell/Publish/blob/master/Documentation/HowTo/SyntaxHighlighting/using-splash.md) to actually see colors in your swift code blocks:

> That’ll automatically highlight all code blocks (except the ones marked using no-highlight). However, to actually see the syntax highlighting rendered within a web browser, you also need to define a set of CSS styles corresponding to the classes that Splash will assign to each code token. An example CSS file can be [found here](https://github.com/JohnSundell/Splash/blob/master/Examples/sundellsColors.css).